# NestJS Cron jobs import no service Injection

Tags: cron, nestjs, constructor-injection

I am trying to create a super simple cron task

```
@Injectable()
export class CronService {
    constructor(
        @Inject(forwardRef(() => PurchaseService))
        private purchaseService: PurchaseService) {}

    @Cron('45 * * * * *')
    handleCron() {
        this.purchaseService.handleOldPurchases();
    }
}
```

when I define the service in the module in the `imports` section, it runs only if I drop the purchase service injectionm if I add it to the `providers` section - it simply doesn't run in production :(

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        CronService, 
    ],
```

runs the cron - but throws `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CronService (?). Please make sure that the argument PurchaseService at index [0] is available in the CronService context.`

```
@Module({
    providers: [
        CronService, 
    ],
```

doesn't run at all

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/modules says _imports: the list of imported **modules** that export the providers which are required in this module_ `CronService` is a provider, so you should add it to the `providers` array of its module.

Comment: try to follow the sample they wrote: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/80c538b8a33f244d1923c4e818b639a2b7175bdd/sample/27-scheduling

Comment: you're right, it should be a provider, but add it to the provider's list - it runs on my local machine, but not on production, really strange ...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and just figured it out. Turns out I needed to import the `ScheduleModule` **before** the module that implemented the cron job in `AppModule`.

**Didn't run cron:**

```
@Module({
  imports: [SomeCronModule, ScheduleModule.forRoot()],
  controllers: [AppController, UrlController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Ran cron:**

```
@Module({
  imports: [ScheduleModule.forRoot(), SomeCronModule],
  controllers: [AppController, UrlController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `PurchaseService` is in the same module as `CronService`

PurchaseService:

```
@Injectable()
export class PurchaseService {
  handleOldPurchases() {}
}
```

CronService:

```
@Injectable()
export class CronService {
    constructor(private _purchaseService: PurchaseService) {}

    @Cron('45 * * * * *')
    handleCron() {
        this._purchaseService.handleOldPurchases();
    }
}
```

CronModule:

```
@Module({
    providers: [CronService, PurchaseService]
})
export class CronModule {}
```

If your `CronService` and `PurchaseService` are in different modules, the module that contains `PurchaseService` has to provide and export `PurchaseService` and the module that consumes the `PurchaseService` has to import the `PurchaseModule`

PurchaseModule:

```
@Module({
    providers: [PurchaseService],  // this tells the interpreter this module offers PurchaseService 
    exports: [PurchaseService]  // this tells the interpreter for those modules that import PurchaseModule can have access to PurchaseService
})
export class PurchaseModule {}
```

CronModule:

```
@Module({
    imports: [PurchaseModule] // this tells the interpreter this module require some services in PurchaseModule 
    providers: [CronService],
})
export class CronModule {}
```

Lastly, only use forwardRef() if and only if services are mutually dependent, i.e. Service A consumes methodB() of Service B, while Service B is also consuming methodA of Service A. IMHO, you should try your best to avoid this kind of coupling.

If you need more help, NestJS discord: https://discord.com/invite/nestjs

Comment: I was using providers, without forwardRef, for some unclear reason this is working well in dev but not working at all in production unless my cron is in the imports, also, all the examples on nestjs show adding as a import, which is slightly confusing